# Docker Madlib Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos7, madlib

I was trying to install Apache MADLib on Postgres. Having difficulty with YUM approach I moved to Docker approach as suggested by this website https://pgxn.org/dist/madlib/

I was able to pull docker image as suggested at para 1. Now at para 2 I am stuck with comment "Path to incubator-madlib directory". I am not able to understand whether it should be the URL to MADLib Incubator such as "https://github.com/apache/incubator-madlib" or it should refer to local disk area. It would be great by giving an example of how to run this command.

*2) Launch a container corresponding to the MADlib image, mounting the
source code folder to the container:*

```
docker run -d -it --name madlib \ -v (path to incubator-madlib directory):/incubator-madlib/ madlib/postgres_9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The `(path to incubator-madlib directory)` refers to wherever you have git cloned the MADlib code base to on your machine. Say for example, your home directory in your machine is `/home/xyz/` and you have cloned the MADlib code base there, you should have a directory called `/home/xyz/incubator-madlib`. You can now run the docker command documented in the MADlib repo as follows:

`docker run -d -it --name madlib -v /home/xyz/incubator-madlib/:/incubator-madlib/ madlib/postgres_9.6`

You were probably getting the `Permission denied docker:...` error after trying Robert's suggestion because the `$(pwd)` was not referring to your incubator-madlib source code folder, but was referring to `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data`, which should not be the case. In any case, it might be a better idea to provide the `incubator-madlib` directory's absolute path in the docker command, as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

As is documented, that is the directory on your computer where the source code resides:

> where incubator-madlib is the directory where the MADlib source code resides.

So, supossing that you have downloaded the source code in `./incubator-madlib`, run as this:

```
docker run -d -it --name madlib -v $(pwd)/incubator-madlib:/incubator-madlib/ madlib/postgres_9.6
```

Then see what the container logs:

```
docker logs -f madlib
```

Comment: Hi Robert,
Thanks for a quick reply. Please note that I am neewbee to docker. I want to quickly get madlib up and running. Been trying for 48 hours.

I used same command as given in Para-1 viz.,:   
1) Pull down the madlib/postgres_9.6:latest image from docker hub:
docker pull madlib/postgres_9.6:latest

It should have gone to default location. Using the command:

docker run -d -it --name madlib -v $(/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data):/incubator-madlib/ madlib/postgres_9.6 

Error: Permission denied
docker: invalid reference format
See 'docker run --help'